# Timer on live wallpaper-Android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, countdowntimer

i am making a Live Wallpaper for Android.i would like to know how to show countdown timer in live wallpaper.A helping hand would be much appreciated.Can i add textview within live wallpaper to show timer in text.i would like to show timer in days,hours,minutes and seconds if possible

Comment: For making countdown timer method is available on official docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: @Karimkhan hi,i know that.but how to show countdown within live wallpaper app?

Comment: You can draw it using Canvas.

Comment: @ChiralCode can you share me code.i am a beginner and am not skilled in coding

Comment: @ChiralCode can you please share code

Comment: I cannot share code, because I don't have any.